# What does it mean to have 3 brackets after array?

Tags: php, brackets

I am curious as to what the `args['fields'][$k]['order']` means. I am new to PHP and so far I know that `args['fields']` would mean that the user is talking about the value for the key `'fields'` in the array `args`. But what does it mean to have 3 brackets (all containing something) after the `args` part?

```
foreach($this->args['fields'] as $k => $field){
            if(!isset($field['order']))
                $this->args['fields'][$k]['order'] = 10;
```

Comment: Your array has 3 dimensions!

Comment: Ahh...so it's basically saying that in the `args` array, look for the `'fields'` array, and within that look for the `'order'` field and put the value of 10?

Comment: Do: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->args);` this will show it pretty good :)

Comment: I'm curious as to why my question got a downvote now...would anyone like to explain what I could do to format this into a better question? I thought the premise was fundamentally valid....

Comment: I haven't downvoted you but I suspect the feeling is that you could have found the answer in any PHP tutorial covering arrays. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that `args` is a three dimensional array. The key `'fields'` in `args` points to an array. The key `$k` in that array points to another array. The key `'order'` in that array is being assigned with the value `10`.